# How to customize a legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have the following dataframes:

```
df <-  tribble(~ id,       ~ type,              ~ value,
               "1",  "Quarterly",  -185.44272504185938,
               "2",  "Quarterly",  2.3461400352210546,
               "3",  "Quarterly",  -3.3506362679401747,
               "4",  "Quarterly",  12.198021733063797,
               "5",  "Quarterly",  39.16805907764865,
               "6",  "Quarterly",  29.258292527180572,
               "7",  "Quarterly",  18.605504231676832,
               "8",  "Quarterly",  61.17282084445469,
               "9",  "Quarterly",  115.76795844352,
               "10", "Quarterly",  90.3473788015599,
               "1",   "Monthly",  473.42922462885326,
               "2",   "Monthly",  -10.579657811202168,
               "3",   "Monthly",  14.88866793035703,
               "4",   "Monthly",  0.9983391011546701,
               "5",   "Monthly",  -0.8838179658391709,
               "6",   "Monthly",  78.33644128716827,
               "7",   "Monthly",  92.38129375625499,
               "8",   "Monthly",  226.60868103438406,
               "9",   "Monthly",  295.9518745997166,
               "10",   "Monthly",  412.9794644618978)

df_aux <-  tribble(~ id,    ~ type,         ~ value,
                   "1", "Yearly", 287.9864995869939,
                   "2", "Yearly", -8.233517775981113,
                   "3", "Yearly", 11.538031662416856,
                   "4", "Yearly", 13.196360834218467,
                   "5", "Yearly", 38.28424111180948,
                   "6", "Yearly", 107.59473381434884,
                   "7", "Yearly", 110.98679798793182,
                   "8", "Yearly", 287.78150187883875,
                   "9", "Yearly", 411.7198330432366,
                   "10","Yearly", 503.3268432634577)

ggplot(df, aes(reorder(id, value), value, fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", width = .6) +
  geom_point(data = df_aux, aes(id, value), shape = 23, color = "white", size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00a79d", "#9dd4cf", "#012169")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-200, 700, by = 100),
                     limits = c(-200, 700)) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(fill = "",
       x = "",
       y = "",
       title = "Some title",
       subtitle = "Some subtitle") +
  theme_minimal()
```

The problem I am having here is in the first place the legends of type, they look different from the desired output:

[image]

But also, how can I change the colors from the id 10 without it appearing on the legend? It seems ggplot2 does not allow to modify manually a legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the legend shape using `key_glyph` and then manually specify the shape by `type` the same way you have done for `fill`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(reorder(id, value), value, shape = type, fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", width = .6, key_glyph = "point") +
  geom_point(data = df_aux, aes(id, value), color = "white", size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00a79d", "#9dd4cf", "#012169"), name = "") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Yearly" = 23, "Quarterly" = 22, "Monthly" = 22), name = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-200, 700, by = 100),
                     limits = c(-200, 700)) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(fill = "",
       x = "",
       y = "",
       title = "Some title",
       subtitle = "Some subtitle") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

EDIT: If you want to show ID 10 separately, I'd suggest using `ggnewscale` to apply a second fill scale. This is getting into "off-label" use of ggplot2, so it will take more wrangling to get the point to appear on top for that series, and to hide the legend.

```
library(ggnewscale)
ggplot(df, aes(reorder(id, value), value, shape = type, fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", width = .6, key_glyph = "point") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00a79d", "#9dd4cf", "#012169"), name = "") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Yearly" = 23, "Quarterly" = 22, "Monthly" = 22), name = "") +
  geom_point(data = df_aux, aes(id, value), color = "white", size = 3) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(data = df[which(df$id == "10"),], aes(fill = type),
           position = "stack", stat = "identity", width = .6, key_glyph = "point") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#68b6ea", "#9dc4dd"), name = "") +
  ...
```

[image]

Comment: This was really helpful for the first problem! I am still battling with changing the colors of the bar corresponding the id number 10l

Comment: Updated. There might also be a way to better accomplish this by creating new `types` specific to ID 10, and hiding those in the legend. That would solve the issue I had of the point being behind ID 10's bars because of the plot order necessitated by the new fill scale....